# Apache Velocity: $request.getHeader('referer') giving unexpected results

Tags: http-status-code-404, velocity, referrer, http-referer

On my 404 error page, I want to display the referer URL and then use it to run a search to attempt to find the correct page.

In my header Velocity template file, I'm using

```
$response.sendRedirect("$link.requestBaseURL/404_page_not_found_7_293?t=$date.getSystemTime()")
```

to refer the user to a 404 page when they attempt to access an old-style page (these old pages are no longer intended to be accessed, but some of them may still be indexed by Google).

On the 404 page itself, I'm using

```
#set($referrer = $request.getHeader('referer'))
```

to get the referer, but instead of displaying the URL of the page that referred the user to the 404 page, it displays the URL of the page they accessed before that! For example, if you go to the homepage of the site, then click on a broken link that forwards to the 404 page - the referer is given as the homepage, rather than the broken link.

How can I get the correct referer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirections don't change the Referer header. Even if it's not clear in the HTTP 1.1 RFC, it's the policy of most browsers.

Your best option is to pass the faulty URL as a query parameter from the broken page itself.